# Elasticsearch 2.0 can see data in Indices from browser tab

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-stack

I have Elasticsearch 2.0 running on windows 7 local machine, connected to Mysql DB waiting on new entries and all works fine. I am using a cluster with 3 nodes. Cluster Health is green.

Elasticsearch

[image]

when I click on the browser tab and then on the Indices I want to look at it seem to be empty even though it says there are 2 documents?

[image]

when I open the Any Request tab and do a search for the Indices `"audit-2015.11.20"` it returns the data? have I to configure something else?

[image]

Elasticsearch location on windows is `C:\elasticsearch-2.0.0`

[image]

I start each Elasticsearch individually from cmd like so: `C:\elasticsearch-2.0.0\elasticsearch-2.0.0-Master\bin>elasticsearch` changing the name for each.

Am I forgetting to do something. My configurations file for `elasticsearch-2.0.0-Master` is as follows.

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration     =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
  cluster.name: AppTransport
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
  node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
# bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind adress to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
  http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Elasticsearch nodes will find each other via unicast, by default.
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
  discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:9201", "127.0.0.1:9202"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
# action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

on the other Elasticsearch yaml configuration file I have just changed the Node **node.name** the Network **http.port** numbers and Discovery **discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts**.

so node 2 is `http.port: 9201`  and discovery is discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: `["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:9201", "127.0.0.1:9202"]` and node 3 is `http.port: 9202`  and discovery is discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: `["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:9201", "127.0.0.1:9202"]`.

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but if you refresh your browser completely and reload the page, do you see something in the browser tab of the plugin after clicking the index? The head plugin is not always correctly refreshing itself. Also have you tried the blue "Refresh" button at the top right of the head plugin?

Comment: Hey val,  ye tried refreshing, restarting nodes in different order. Starting only 2 nodes too. Deleting everything and starting again and none seem to work. I will download Kibana later and a different plugin to see if that helps.

Comment: Can you open the Inspector (depends on which browser you are) and see if you have Javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Yes didn't think of that, I will try that and let you know thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for elasticsearch-head. It does not fully work with the current 2.x versions for now.

One of the issues is the following: https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/issues/217